# how does padding work in structure?

Tags: c

The output of this program is 28. I don't understand how?
According to me this should be 32(4+4+4+4+12)+4(to maintain the alignment)=32.
Please explain the reason for displaying the output 28??

```
struct test{
    char c;
    int d;
    int x;
    int y;
    long double p;
    }t1;

printf("%d",sizeof(t1));
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Does it really have 12bytes `long double`?

Comment: Btw you should not rely on how padding works.

Comment: @K-ballo, 'sizeof(long double)' is 12 on my machine. (x64, gcc 4.5.3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [structure padding and structure packing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your "long double" is actually the same as a double (8 bytes), and if you're on a 32bit processor the alignment is 4-byte.

4+4+4+4+8 = 24

What is `sizeof(long double)`?

**EDIT:**

I used GCC's `__builtin_offset_of()` and `__alignof__` to investigate.  The actual answer that explains the size of the struct is:

4+4+4+4+12 = 28

`sizeof(long double)` is 12.

No padding is necessary because `__alignof__(long double)` is 4 and.  Interestingly, `__alignof__(double)` is 8.

Comment: No, I am using the GCC compiler(Code Blocks) and sizeof(long double) is 12. And the processor is also 64bit and in that processor the alignment for long double is considered as 16bytes.

Comment: Ok, my guess was wrong.  On my machine with gcc 4.4.0 (target: mingw32), `sizeof(long double)` is 12 and the size of that struct is 28.

Comment: please tell me the procedure of how did u investigate through the said method. I searched for the alignment of long double on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and according to this the alignment for long double is 16.

Comment: I just ran this code:  `printf("%d,%d\n", sizeof(long double), __alignof__(long double));`

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked to says that long doubles are "4-byte aligned with GCC" for a 32-bit system and 16-byte aligned for a 64-bit system.  The compiler you are running probably targets x86 (32-bit) so it can run on 32-bit or 64-bit computers.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), long doubles in gcc 32-bit mode (using `gcc -m32` or with a gcc that was built to produce 32-bit output, regardless of what your platform actually is) are only 4-byte aligned. Might be good to consult the gcc manual to verify that, though.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64 bit system sizes are
char - 1 byte(its not 4 bytes)
int - 4 bytes
long double - 12 bytes

so total is 1+4+4+4+12+padding = 28 bytes!!

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1, yes, but the int following that char must be 4-byte aligned, so the compiler will add 3 bytes of padding between c and d.

Answer (score 0):

That seems right to me.  A field immediately following p would be 4-byte aligned, so there's no need for padding at the end of the structure.

4+4+4+4+12=28

On my system, the output is 32, but on my system, sizeof(long double) is 16. (x86_64, LLVM3).

Answer (score 0):

The 28 `sizeof` output is of course correct = 1 byte for char, 3 bytes padding, 3 x 4 int and 12 bytes for long double (96 bits size but 80 bit precision), which makes in total 28 bytes.

Remember that even tho you compile on x86-64 machine, you probably compile for x86-32 machine using mingw32 and that makes a difference.

Mingw32 uses 4 byte allignement for `long double`.