# How does padding work in a C compiler

Tags: c, memory, struct, alignment, padding

I am trying to understand how padding works in a 32 bit compiler. I have boiled it down to the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define uchar unsigned char
#define ushort unsigned short

typedef struct  {                               
    ushort  a;
    ushort  b[60];
} INNER;

typedef struct{
    uchar z;
    INNER x;

}OUTER;

int main(void) {

    printf("%d\n",sizeof(INNER));
    printf("%d",sizeof(OUTER));
    return 0;
}
```

And the output of this program is:

```
122 /*actual*/
124 /*actual*/
```

My expectation however is

```
124 /*expectation*/
126 /*expectation */
```

Now, as far as I understand, if there was any padding that was necessary, it should have been in the INNER structure. i.e. INNER structure should have been padded as follows:

```
typedef struct  {                               
    ushort  a;
    ushort  b[60];
    ushort compiler_pad; /* I believe compiler should have done this */
}
```

But instead, I think compiler is doing the following:

```
typedef struct{
    uchar z;
    INNER x;
    uchar compiler_pad; /* I believe compiler is doing this */
}OUTER;
```

Does anyone know why the parent structure is being padded, instead of correcting the alignment of inner structure?

Additional details:
- sizeof(uchar) is 1
- sizeof(ushort) is 2
- I am on a 32 bit processor and alignment is 4
- I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743619/how-does-padding-work-in-structure) question

Comment: Just so you know, `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1`. It's in the C specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INNER` is 61 `ushort` scalars in a row, which fits exactly into 122 bytes; *when allocated by itself*, it doesn't require any padding.  That is why there is no padding inside an `INNER`.

`OUTER`, however, consists of one `uchar` (whose size is 1 *by definition*) and then 61 `ushort`s. The hardware alignment requirement for `ushort` is 2, not 1, so the compiler must insert one byte of padding between the `uchar` and the 61 `ushort`s, i.e. *before* the `INNER` object, so that their alignment requirement is satisfied.  Padding at the *end* of the `INNER` as you expected would not arrange for `INNER` to be properly aligned within `OUTER`.

**EDIT:** The compiler is inserting padding *in between* `z` and `x`, *not* at the end of `OUTER`:

```
typedef struct {
    uchar z;
    uchar compiler_pad;
    INNER x;
} OUTER;
```

You can confirm this for yourself by adding `#include <stddef.h>` at the top of your program and then printing `offsetof(OUTER, x)`.  The number printed will be 2.